# ASP.NET can't get link to work

Tags: asp.net, href

I tried 2 methods for redirecting to an other page

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="asd" ViewStateMode="Disabled" 
    NavigateUrl="f2.aspx" runat="server" >HERE!</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

and the code behind the button:

```
Response.Redirect("f2.aspx");
```

and for some reason - neither of them work! when i click them them i stay on the same page with a weird URL (see picture)
What did I do wrong??
[image]

Comment: It should be the full "Doctor Who" not "Dr."

Comment: You might have placed the page f2.aspx into a restricted location. Your app is forcing you to authenticate and has the link to your page in the `ReturnUrl` query string variable. Just make sure you're logged in or place the f2.aspx page in a different location.

Comment: @asawyer I just quickly had to fill some DB for it :) no sense behind the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configured Forms Authentication in Web.config to require the user to be logged in.

Until the user is logged in, ASP.Net will redirect to the configured login page.

Comment: Beat me to it... I was mid-response

Comment: i'm using the default template, how do I disable ?

Comment: By editing Web.config.  Consult the documentation where necessary.

Comment: k found it not as hard as i thought :) tnx